# Will a Wifi client transmit (a lot) when no actual data is send?

Tags: client, wifi, traffic, network-traffic

I want to create a rather large number of Wifi clients that each will run a tiny HTTP-server. The clients will never send HTTP requests themselves, they will only accept HTTP requests. They will be queried for data.

Given this, and the fact that the number of requests sent to these clients will be minimal (a few per day), will this setup generate a lot of traffic (low-level) between these clients and the router?

What will be the impact on the radiation? Will the client radiate constantly or only once and a while to discover access-points and so one?